# copy of temp char array from for loop to another array

Tags: arrays, c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I have a function that gets a const char * data and goes through every byte of makes some bit manipulation and then adds it to another char array, so basically one byte input data should be 4 bytes and 2 bytes should be 8 bytes and so on, however I'm not getting the correct results, I'm not sure if I'm using the memcpy correctly here, any help would be appreciated

```
int encryptDataAndSend(const char *logName, const char *data)
{
  const int len = strlen(data);
  printf("data length: %d \n", strlen(data));
  char encryptedData[len * 4];
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
  {
    uint8_t v1 = 255;
    uint8_t v2 = 255;
    uint8_t v3 = 255;
    uint8_t v4 = 255;

    char temp[4] = {0};

    printf("char is %d \n", data[i]);

    v1 |= ((data[i] & (1 << 0)) << 2);
    v1 |= ((data[i] & (1 << 1)) << 5);
    v2 |= ((data[i] & (1 << 2)) << 2);
    v2 |= ((data[i] & (1 << 3)) << 5);
    v3 |= ((data[i] & (1 << 4)) << 2);
    v3 |= ((data[i] & (1 << 5)) << 5);
    v4 |= ((data[i] & (1 << 6)) << 2);
    v4 |= ((data[i] & (1 << 7)) << 5);
    temp[0] = v1;
    temp[1] = v2;
    temp[2] = v3;
    temp[3] = v4;
    printf("temp: %s \n", temp);
    memcpy(encryptedData, temp, strlen(temp));
  }
  printf("temp var: %s", encryptedData);
  const int txBytes = uart_write_bytes(UART_NUM_2, encryptedData, strlen(encryptedData));
  ESP_LOGI(logName, "Wrote %d bytes", txBytes);
  ESP_LOG_BUFFER_HEX("SENDDATA_TAG", encryptedData, txBytes);
  return txBytes;
}
```

This is how I call the function

```
encryptDataAndSend(TX_TASK_TAG, "@BF");
```

Comment: All the `v*` variables are inside the `for` loop and initialized to 0xFF, then you perform bitwise OR with whatever number it is, the result will remain 0xFF... so `temp[0..3]` will always contain 0xFF. What do I miss here?

Comment: ...also `printf("temp: %s \n", temp);` invokes undefined behavior since you print it as a null terminated string but there is no `\0` at the end. You probably need to define it as `char temp[5] = {0};`

Comment: same for `memcpy(encryptedData, temp, strlen(temp));`... the behavior of `strlen(temp)` in you case is undefined.

Comment: @AlexLop actually what I'm trying to do is to set the 2nd and 5th bit of v* for every input byte's bit, so the input byte would split into 4 bytes and the values would be scattered into bit 2 and 5 of the v*

Comment: In that case you need to initialize those variables to 0. 255 - means all the bits are set at the very beginning

Comment: @AlexLop. setting the variable to 0, and now nothing gets added to the encrypted data.How should I go about setting the 2nd and 5th bit of variables based on the bits of the input byte?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do but I think you want to set bits 2 and 5 if the relevant bit in `data` is set, so just normalize the check if specific bit is set to `0` or `1`, by `!!`, like this: `(!!(data[i] & (1 << 0)) << 2)`... just do it for all the statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem with

```
memcpy(encryptedData, temp, strlen(temp));
```

As temp may or may not have a null character. So `strlen` will be incorrect

Perhaps

```
memcpy(encryptedData, temp, 4);
```

Is the right solution.

**EDIT**

In addition encrypted data needs to move forward in each increment of the loop

ie.

```
memcpy(encryptedData + 4 * i, temp, 4);
```

Also perhaps change

```
char encryptedData[len * 4];
```

to

```
char encryptedData[len * 4 + 1];
```

and then

```
encryptedData[len * 4] = 0;
```

to ensure that the string has a null character in it!

Comment: after changing that I'm still getting the wrong data, for example if I use encryptDataAndSend(TX_TASK_TAG, "@"); it gives the same result as if I use encryptDataAndSend(TX_TASK_TAG, "@BF");

Comment: Thanks, where would I use encryptedData[len * 4] = 0; also now I'm getting only ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff, that can't be because of the bit manipulation that I'm doing.

Comment: At the end of the loop. You need to debug further your bit manipulation.